# Moving layered navigation below product toolbar in layout.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, layered-navigation, product-list

I'm having some issues re-ordering elements within following file:

`[MyTheme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

I'm trying to move the layered navigation below the product toolbar, above the products grid.

I've tried, the following:

```
<move element="sidebar.main" destination="category.products.list" after="product_list_toolbar"/>


   <move element="catalog.navigation.renderer" destination="category.products.list" after="product_list_toolbar"/>
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.products.list" after="product_list_toolbar"/>
    move element="catalog.navigation.state" destination="category.products.list" after="product_list_toolbar" />
```

This removes the filter entirely, instead of moving it.

Am I correct to try and move this element within the theme `catalog_category_view.xml`? Or should this be moved with a custom Layered Navigation module ?

An update on this, i was able to move the layered nav to the top of the page via

```
 <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" before="category.products"/>
```

if i set the destination to any more deeply nested blocks the nav just disappears.

I've also tried to move the product toolbar around the layered nav, like so

```
    <move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="content" before="-"/>
```

The nav is still appearing above the toolbar though.

Comment: 4th move  element does not start properly  `move element="catalog.navigation.state"`

Comment: That was just a copy and paste error, i'm still not able to see the filter. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution i came up with is as follows:

```
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.product.list.additional" before="-"/>
```

Comment: I am trying to do something very similar, moving LayeredNavigation above the toolbar. I have tried this with no luck.
`<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" before="-"/>
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.products" before="-"/>
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.products.list" before="-"/>
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.view.container" before="-"/>`
**None of this worked**
although you above solution worked(which bring the layered navigation below toolbar).

what am i doing wrong

Comment: It worked on category page, but did not worked on search page.

Comment: @Arun, idk why no, but for me works perfectly :)
Just add this line from comment in your theme in `catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml`

Comment: @ArunKarnawat, to make this work in search page, you need to use `<move element="catalogsearch.leftnav" destination="content">`, by using `catalogsearch.leftnav` instead of `catalog.leftnav`.

Answer (score 1):

This is answer to show to move Layered navigation above product toolbar using layout xml. Create a file in your theme in Magento_LayeredNavigation module catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml as below -

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="catalog-leftnav-top" as="catalog-leftnav-top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="catalog-leftnav-top" before="category.products"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="catalog-leftnav-top" before = "-"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the options above and none of them worked for putting the layered nav above the toolbar. What finally worked for me was to add code in:

```
"{magento-folder}\app\design\frontend\{yourVendor}\{yourTheme}\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml"
```

The code:

```
<body>
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content.top" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the short answer, for those who are struggling with this confusing answers like me:

copy

"{magento-folder}\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml"

to

"{magento-folder}\app\design\frontend\{yourVendor}\{yourTheme}\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml"

and add the line `<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.product.list.additional" before="-"/>` inside this file right under the `<body>` - tag

```
<body>
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.product.list.additional" before="-"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

If you use 3-column-view and you don´t have another widgets/content in the sidebar.main it could be possible, that the sidebar and 3-column-view disappears because there is no other content and magento removes empty columns/div etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i came up with is as follows:

"{magento-folder}\app\design\frontend{yourVendor}{yourTheme}\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml"

```
<move element="sidebar.main" destination="content" after="-"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To moving the navigation state/leftnav under the toolbar.

1. Page category

- Override the layout catalog_category_view.xml in your theme path and
  add

```
<container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
```

inside of block name="category.products.list"

- Move catalog.navigation.state or catalog.leftnav by this way to  category.product.list.additional  in the same layout.

```
<move element="catalog.navigation.state" destination="category.product.list.additional" />
```

1. Page categorySearch

- Override the layout catalogsearch_result_index.xml in your theme path
  add

```
<block class="Amasty\Shopby\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalogsearch.navigation.state.search" as="state_search" />
```

inside of block name="category.products.list"

- update template of the block with name category.products.list (`Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml`) and add this code `<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('state_search') ?>`
  under  `<?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>`